# Quasi-compact, quasi-separated

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am now learning about quasi-compact and quasi-separated morphism of schemes. I know that the examples for schemes, but I am having trouble finding out the examples for morphism of schemes:

1. Non-quasi-compact morphism of scheme
2. Non-quasi-separated morphism of scheme
3. Quasi-compact but non-quasi-separated morphism of scheme

Thanks!

Comment: You realize how 3. would give you examples of 1. and 2. automatically?

Comment: It is technically not a duplicate of the question, however you find an example of 3. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/256244/211913

Comment: I know 3 can give 2 automatically. But how can 3 give 1?

Comment: By definition, if $X \to Y$ is not qs, then $X \to X \times_Y X$ is not qc.

Comment: Furthermore, the linked answer explicitly constructs an open set, that is not quasi-compact.

Comment: @MooS Thank you!